# Slow down internet without changing router settings

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, internet, wifi-configuration, internet-speed

I know some may think this is a dumb question or that what I am looking for is not the right solution, but I really need your help. This is my situation: my younger sister dropped school, and now all she does is being online on her laptop. I don't even see her sleep anymore, all she does is being online, I wouldn't mind if she would do something productive online, but she doesn't. Parents don't even care and I already tried talking to her many times, nothing seems to work. So I want start slowing down her internet connection to encourage her to start doing other activities.

I know I could do this with QoS in the router but my router doesn't have those settings and living in a pretty poor country I really can't afford buying a new one, plus she could use granpa, aunts, or my older sister internet. I tried editing the QoS Bandwidth Reserve Limit on windows (XP), but that didn't have any effect, I enabled it and set it to 90% and restarted the computer and the speed is the same. Also tested 3 or 4 softwares I found on google but they are all pretty obvious, they keep an icon on the systray and it's easy to notice them.

I need something like a registry hack, or a process that wont show a tray icon or window, or maybe some startup script that would try to download (and then delete) a (or multiple) temp file like those from http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html, enough to slow down internet so youtube and online games are not usable anymore. She connects only via wifi and uses windows XP.

**Does someone knows a software or a solution for this?** *(please reply only the tech aspect, not the family issue)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We really don't need the backstory.  Just ask what you want to do remove everything else.  QoS really isn the only solution for what you want.  Everything else ( software ) can be modified by the user.

Comment: What model router ?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on automatc updates.This will use your internet and probably slow down your speed.